# Beamer : remove the number page of the first slide

Tags: beamer

l set page numbering as follow :

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

However l don't want to page the first slide which containts title name ....

Answer (score 3):

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```

Comment: this solution removes the first slide

Comment: @vincent75 Can you make a MWE that demonstrates the problem? I don't see any disappearing frames.

Comment: I think your method removes the footer entirely. Would it be possible to only remove the numbering from only the first slide?